# Javascript DOM send value to function embedded in iframe to simulate keypress

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

I have a test that I have been working on, trying to send a value to a function defined within an iframe (both pages from the same source). The content of the iframe when in focus responds to certain keystrokes. What I would like to achieve is triggering those keypress actions from the iframe by means of a button on the primary page.

The content of the iframe is dynamic, and needs to function without refreshing, otherwise I know I could change the iframe src to carry the variables. What I have so far...

Parent Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<style>
  iframe{border:1px solid blue;height:100px;width:100px;margin:20px auto 0 auto;}
</style>
</head><body>
<iframe id="iframe" src="iframetest2.html"></iframe>
<button onclick="simKey(32);">CLICK</button>
<script>
  var iframe=document.getElementById('iframe');
  var ifContent=iframe.contentWindow
  function simKey(x){
    ifContent.postMessage(testScript(x),'*','[transfer]');
  }
</script></body></html>
```

And the iFrame content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<script>
  function testScript(x){
document.body.innerHTML=x;
setTimeout(function(){document.body.innerHTML='';},700);
  }
  </script></head><body onkeypress="testScript(event.keyCode)"></body></html>
```

I am also trying to avoid the use of jQuery if possible. This is a concept web design, and really want to hand-write the Javascript so that I can modify as need be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, inline js (like `onkeypress` in your html) is a bad practice. Read some these results: https://www.google.com/search?q=Why+is+inline+js+bad%3F

I will be using the best practice `addEventListener`.

### Fire iFrame keypress event from button on parent window:

[**Live demo (click).**](http://plnkr.co/edit/cHawL0pIF8bwBbNnsls6?p=preview)

**Main Page:**

```
var myBtn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
var iframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');

myBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var evt = new Event('keypress');
  evt.keyCode = '115';
  iframe.contentDocument.body.dispatchEvent(evt);
});
```

**iFrame:**

```
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  console.log(e.keyCode);
});
```

Here are some docs that might help you if you need to support older browsers or want more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

#### Old Answer: this listens to keypresses on the parent window.

In the iFrame, you just need to have this JavaScript:

```
window.parent.document.body.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  console.log(e.keyCode);
});
```

Comment: Change your iframe.JS with : `window.parent.addEventListener('keypress', function() {
  console.log('iFrame keypress func fired!');
});` maybe window.parent.somehting.add...

Comment: @NetaMeta It does work, but I forgot to delegate the same event. I made a note I'm about to update it =D

Comment: @NetaMeta ah heck, that's way better than re-firing the event. I didn't think of that! Why don't you just post that? You should get the credit.

Comment: nah was your solution you beat me to it

Comment: I was only using the button to tie a value to the function being fired, my actual page is using event listeners for the keystrokes and qualifying them through a series of if-else statements.The listeners aren't really what I was hoping for on the parent page, I was looking to make some buttons that could fire off functions for any user who doesn't have access to a keyboard. It is a hybridization of game/website/resume, just trying to increase useability for tablets.

Comment: @ThomasCheney oh dohhh, that's why I did it the original way...I'm so scatter brained. Give me a sec to put my answer back the way it was =D

Comment: You can use any function you define both directions. if you want to fire a function on parent from iframe you used window.parent.funcname(var); and if from parent to child simply call the function.

Comment: @ThomasCheney To expand on the comment above, just keep in mind that all of this is based on being able to share windows between the main page and iframe. You don't have to use a keypress in the iframe. If there's no keyboard anyway, you're manually entering the keyCode, so you could just as soon pass any number directly to a function of the iFrame's window, etc....many approaches are possible.

Comment: I had to reread the code a few times to really grasp what I was looking at, but this is perfect. I thought about going button-only. The issue is that if one has a keyboard to use it is much faster and more comfortable, although mouseclicks/touchstarts on the screen will be important as well. May go with listeners so I can preventDefault(); keys instead.